# How to use ribbon in catel DataWindow

Tags: wpf, catel

I need to use ribbon in the catel:DataWindow.
I tried using fluent ribbon but not work in last catel version.

```
<catel:DataWindow x:Class="STK_Lite.Views.MainWindow"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"

              xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:Itenso.Windows.Controls.ListViewLayout;assembly=Itenso.Windows.Controls.ListViewLayout"
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              xmlns:fluent="clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent">

<Grid>
    <fluent:Ribbon>
        <fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="TEMPL">
            <fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="CEATE TEMPL">
                <fluent:Button Name="ButtonCreateConf"
                               Command="{Binding Path=OpenFileXmlConfig}"
                               Header="CONFIG"
                               Size="Large">
                    <fluent:Button.LargeIcon>
                        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource XmlConfigDriver}" />
                    </fluent:Button.LargeIcon>
                </fluent:Button>
            </fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
        </fluent:RibbonTabItem>
</Grid>
```

> I have to use instead FluentWindow catelDataWindow. But i have to use catel:DataWindow. 
>   Ribbon is not displayed.

I need help. Ribbon in Catel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually provided out of the box shells for Catel in a project called [Orchestra](https://github.com/wildgums/orchestra). It contains the following shells:

- Ribbon.Fluent
- MahApps

I recommend that you check out the Ribbon.Fluent example where all the hard work is already done for you (together with many other conveniences).

Comment: I tried to create a project with the orchestra.  But I did not find the template in VS 2012. I did not like the ribbon through the setup code.
Could not another way to add ribbon in the latest version of the catel?

Comment: You can create the ribbon in any view you want, the only thing Orchestra is asking from you is to return the ribbon inside a service. Catel is just an MVVM framework, it can work with any type of app. Orchestra is a convenience wrapper around Catel so you don't have to worry about boiler plate code.